# QGIS Crashes when I connect to QGIS Cloud

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.6, qgis-cloud

QGIS crashes when I try to connect to QGIS cloud. I just signed up for the cloud service - still testing out the free version.

When I try to connect through the plug-in panel (I use no proxy server) the "wheel" on my mac starts spinning, QGIS stops responding, and I have to force-quit it.

I have tried it with and without the regular Mac firewall, makes no difference.

You can close this it's solved. When you have a problem like this you don't know what's causing it. So it wasn't off-topic. Anyway I solved it myself by getting a new router.

Comment: Cross-posted on http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIs-crashes-when-I-try-to-connect-to-QGIS-cloud-td5179927.html

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is solved. The problem was my faulty Comcast router. The old router was working - that is I could surf the web with it, but it was having trouble with ftp and vpn connections, apparently this also affected the connection to the qgis cloud server, which made qgis unable to connect and eventually crash. So it made it seem a qgis problem, which it wasn't.

Comment: I had issues with QGIS crashing also for the same reason but when I upgraded to QGIS 3.4.2 it stopped.